# Does any protocol exist to ZKP query PID (personal information data) and to incentivise the PID data donors?

Tags: privacy, protocol, zksnark

Does any Ethereum protocol exist to make a ZKP (zero-knowledge proof) query on some PID (personal information data) attribute and to incentivise the PID data donors?

If not, is it hypothetically possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several Ethereum protocols that allow for the use of zero-knowledge proofs (ZKPs) in order to query personal information data (PID) while maintaining the privacy of the data donors. These protocols typically use a combination of smart contracts and ZKPs to enable private queries on sensitive data without revealing the identity of the data donors.

Examples of such protocols include:

- Aztec Protocol: It is an open-source protocol for confidential
  computations on Ethereum, allows for private transaction and private
  data queries
- ZK-Rollup: It is a layer 2 scaling solution for Ethereum
  that uses ZKPs to enable private, low-cost transactions and data
  queries on the Ethereum blockchain
- ZEXE: is a protocol for executing
  private smart contract on Ethereum, that uses ZKP for privacy and
  confidentiality.

Incentivizing data donors is possible by using tokens or other forms of digital assets that can be used to reward data donors for sharing their information. These tokens can be used to incentivize data sharing by providing data donors with a financial benefit for participating in the ecosystem.